# Best sequence when uploading large files to different cloud services

Tags: django, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda

I am trying to upload large files (100+ Gb) to several cloud storage services from a Django app. I have written a first view to do this for S3 and it is working:

```
class FilePolicyAPI(APIView):
...
```

I have written these views for S3 multipart upload, my question is, should I write similar views for the other cloud services (Google Cloud Storage, Azure), or would it be best to implement a S3 lambda function that responds to the upload to the S3 bucket and replicates these files in the other cloud services? What would be less costly for my Web App? thanks

Comment: 1) Do not upload 100 GB files. Did you calculate the data transfer time? 2) Uploads fail very often for big files, break large files into pieces. 3) You pay for bandwidth. Have you calculated the costs? Using an intermediary service can be expensive at ten to twelve cents per GB.

Comment: thanks @JohnHanley, valid input, I can break this into small files, still it needs to be able to accommodate user uploads, let's say in the 1-2 GB range, I have implemented a multipart upload to S3 but now struggling to decide on best course of action regarding sending this to Google Cloud or Azure...

Comment: That is not a question for StackOverflow. When you have a coding problem, we can help you.